# Sort Array of Object in groovy

Tags: arrays, sorting, groovy

I have an Array of Object that is declared and look like this:

```
def meal = [['Apple','Tomatoes', 'Coffee'],['Peach','Broccoli', 'Water'],['Orange','Peas', 'Pepsi'],['Banana','Beans', 'Coffee']]
```

I need to sort these objects based on the third element of each object and then based on the second element. So my output would be:

```
meal = [['Banana','Beans', 'Coffee'], ['Apple','Tomatoes', 'Coffee'],['Orange','Peas', 'Pepsi'],['Peach','Broccoli', 'Water'],]
```

Comment: When you tried it, what difficulty did you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this

```
meal.sort { a, b -> a[2] <=> b[2] ?: a[1] <=> b[1] }
```

When the two are equal, `a[2] <=> b[2]` is `0`, so it runs the second half

Comment: Thank you. Since I was trying to run this in Jenkins, I was not getting the expectation. If anyone comes across this post, this needs to be in a @NonCPS method

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iterate through the desired sorting in reverse order. Hope the following code will help you.

```
def list = [['Apple','Tomatoes', 'Coffee'],['Peach','Broccoli', 'Water'],['Orange','Peas', 'Pepsi'],['Banana','Beans', 'Coffee']];

list = list.sort{ a,b -> a[1] <=> b[1] }
list = list.sort{ a,b -> a[2] <=> b[2] }

println(list);
```